# How to get a caller class of a method

Tags: java

How do I know which class called a method?

```
class A {
   B b = new B();

   public void methodA() {
    Class callerClass = b.getCallerCalss(); // it should be 'A' class
   } 
}

class B {
 public Class getCallerCalss() {
   //... ???
   return clazz;
 }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass Class as parameter to getCallerClass()?

Comment: about editing. - yeah.. sorry for that. thinking on demand.. like refactoring.. TDD kind of.

Comment: passing class as parameter - it is possible but not nice i guess. maybe some magic with reflection could help

Comment: "How to who"
"calss" != "class" != "clazz"

Comment: This question might help: [Java logger that automatically determines caller's class name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/80692/1343161)

Comment: @ses: The editing on the fly is not a very good idea. If you'd like a prompt answer instead of hoping for an eventual "long tail" one, you only have a fairly short window of time to attract attention to your question. If it's cryptic or broken, it's more likely people will navigate to one that isn't.

Comment: Can you give us more information on why you need to know the class of the caller? Generics may be more appropriate depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily done with `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    doSomething();
}

private static void doSomething() {
    System.out.println(getCallerClass());
}

private static Class<?> getCallerClass() {
    final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    String clazzName = stackTrace[3].getClassName();
    try {
        return Class.forName(clazzName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

`[3]` is used because `[0]` is the element for `Thread.currentThread()`, `[1]` is for `getCallerClass`, `[2]` is for `doSomething`, and finally, `[3]` is `main`. If you put `doSomething` in another class, you'll see it returns the correct class.

Answer (score 3):

There's a method of observing the stacktrace

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29)

> The last element of the array represents the bottom of the stack, which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.

Comment: Why is it "not very nice"? Doing logic based on inspecting the stack trace is dubious design, but the method seems just fine if you can accept the performance hit.

Comment: @millimoose, What I meant was the scenario feels more like a `Design` issue to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the class name of the caller class by fetching the second element of the stack trace:

```
final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
System.out.println(stackTrace[1].getClassName());
```

The [`getClassName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getClassName%28%29) method of the [`StackTraceElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) class returns with a `String` so you won't get a `Class` object unfortunately.

Comment: Yes you are right - but you need `stackTrace[1]`: `stackTrace[0].getClassName()` returns `java.lang.Thread`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, it smart way! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Throwable.getStackTrace()`.

Create a new `Throwable`.. you don't have to throw it :).

untested:

```
Throwable t = new Throwable();
StackTraceElement[] es = t.getStackTrace();
// Not sure if es[0] would contain the caller, or es[1]. My guess is es[1].
System.out.println( es[0].getClass() + " or " + es[1].getClass() + " called me.");
```

Obviously if you're creating some function (`getCaller()`) then you'll have to go another level up in the stack trace.