# Why log4j's Logger.getLogger() need pass a Class type?

Tags: java, log4j

I read some articles about how to use log4j.
Most of them give below code as a beginning:

```
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo.Bar");
```

or

```
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XXX.class);
```

This will initialize the logger object.But my question is why need send the class type as a parameter? It seems when I use the logger, I don't care in which class I use it.So the Class type seems no effect to logger.
If I declare a logger as static and public, I can call this logger at another class, So what's the intention of the author to design it like this? Will the Class type bind something when I use the logger? Or I can send any Class types to the getLogger function.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

1. **You can always use any string as logger name other than class type. It's definitely ok.**
2. **The reason why many people use class type, I guess:**

   - Easy to use. You don't need to worry about logger name duplication in a complex Java EE application. If other people also use your logger name, you may have a log file including no only the output of your class;
   - Easy to check the logging class, as the logger name will show in the log file. You can quickly navigate to the specific class;
   - When you distribute you class, people may want to redirect the logging from your class to a specific file or somewhere else. In such case, if you use a special logger name, we may need to check the source code or imposssible to do that if souce is unavailable.

Comment: No, not ANY STRING. I write this in a jsp: Logger.getLogger("fp_check_power.jsp")  and log.debug("..."). However, in the log file it only shows:"[2017/07/12 16:13:21, DEBUG] (jsp) : open url = ....".

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution to it?

Comment: including no only --- i don't understand the sentence, could you explain?

Comment: @LeiYang - I think it's meant to read "you may have a log file including **not** [just] the output of you class". Meaning there could be output from other classes.

Answer (score 9):

From the [javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getLogger(java.lang.Class)): `Logger.getLogger(Class)` is a shorthand for `getLogger(clazz.getName())`.  A convention used with log4j and other logging frameworks is to define a static logger per class.  For example,

```
public class SomeClass {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
    ...
}
```

I have found this convention to work well for organizing logging output.  It's certainly not required but is a useful practice.

Comment: Looks like Logger.getLogger(blah) creates one logger per class, rather than one logger per instance of a class. (I checked by getting logger two times for same class. logger1 == logger2 was true). Why doesn't it create a logger per instance ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 log4j manages the logger instances so that any two logger names (or classes in this case) result in the same instance. The practice of create a static logger instance per class is fairly well established. What are you trying to accomplish with multiple instances?

Comment: I don't need to use multiple instances of logger for the same class. I only want to understand why we prefer to use one instance.

Comment: @testerjoe2 understood. I think it's just the way the API the organized. Logger instances are managed by name.

Answer (score 7):

1:you can use "class name" or "string name" when you define in log4j.properties before,
such as

```
log4j.logger.anything=INFO,anything
```

so,you can record your log as

```
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("anything");
```

2:If you define some log name,you can check it easily,cus they are separate.

Answer (score 1):

You can trace your log by class type.

example1:

```
public class Bar {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo.Bar");
    ...
    logger.debug("debug message");
}
```

Maybe you can see below a log message.

```
DEBUG: **com.foo.Bar** debug message
```

example2:

```
public class Foo {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo.Foo");
    ...
    logger.debug("debug message");
}
```

Maybe you can see below a log message.

```
DEBUG: **com.foo.Foo** debug message
```

If you have a lot of java class and logger message, It's too difficult to find where log messages are from.

Comment: That's useful, but I can format my log content to categorize my log.

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on a specific logging library, but usually it's more than a name. It signifies logger's hierarchy.
When you configure your logger, you would usually pass both Log Level and Logger name, like this:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="ALL"/>
```

This attribute is not just name, it attribute means a hierarchy. And if instead you would write something like:

```
<logger name="org" level="ALL"/>
```

not only hibernate, but everything that is in org package will be impacted.
On the other hand, if you write something like:

`<logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="ALL"/>`

it will only concern hibernate validation package, and not the rest of Hibernate.

By the way, if you don't want to specify a concrete class for every factory, you can use [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80692/java-logger-that-automatically-determines-callers-class-name/32132312#32132312) like(Kotlin):

```
val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass())
```

Answer (score 0):

XXX.class is to Name your Logger i.e to flag subsequent log statements .
To give you an idea which class certain log statements belongs to / originated from.

Answer (score 0):

Logger with class name is not mandatory, you can use your own message. It is convention to use:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XXX.class)
```

and is useful to debug. It will log which line of code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getName()` method.

```
private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class.getName());
```